# Retrieve just some columns using an ORM

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm using [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) and SQL Server 2008 with the [Database First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878) approach.

My problem is :

I have some tables that holds many many columns (~100), and when I try to retrieve a lot of rows it takes a significant time before it returns the results, even if sometimes I need to use just 3 or 4 columns from that table.

I passed half a day in Stackoverflow trying to find a way to solve this problem, and I came up with two solutions :

- Using stored procedures to retrieve data with the columns I want.
- Edit the .edmx (xml) and the .cs files to remove the columns that I won't use.

My problem again is :

- If I use stored procedures to retrieve the data with the columns that I want, Entity Framework loose it benefit and I can use ADO.NET instead of it and call directly the stored procedures ...
- I can't take the second solution, because every time I make a change in the database, I'm obliged to regenerate the .edmx file and I loose the changes I made before :'(

Is there a way to do this somehow in Entity Framework ? *Is that possible* !

I know that other ORMs exist like [NHibernate](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateForNET) or [Dapper](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net), but I don't know if they can offer this feature without causing a lot of pain.

Comment: Have you tried using the `select` keyword in you LINQ expression?

Comment: Why don't you just select the specific columns?

Comment: Are you trying to manipulate entity objects with most columns being lazy loaded ? It is possible with NHibernate

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips I think I didn't explain well my question, I can use the select keywork, but what I want to do, is to be able to manipulate that object (serialize, deserialize) and send him back to the database.

Comment: @jbl since you evokef the Lazy Loading, someone told me to use the Virtual keywork for the properties of the object to achieve this. But I don't know how !

Comment: yes NH lazy loaded classes must be virtual, so that the ORM be able to create transparent proxies, inheriting from it, to handle lazy-loaded properties. Anyway, switching a project to an ORM you never used before, just for this feature, seems like overkill to me.

Comment: @Schneider if you're sending the entities over the wire, then you're coupling your database model with a remote system, I'd avoid doing this and look into flattening your entities into messages or DTOs.

Comment: Have you tried removing unwanted proprties in the designer (as opposed to the edmx file)? This should result in a "narrowed" entity. I don't think it is a good idea to remove columns/properties directly in the edmx file - especially in the store schema.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to return every column each time. You can specify which columns you need.

```
var query  = from t in db.Table
             select new { t.Column1, t.Column2, t.Column3 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally if you project the data into a different poco it will do this automatically in EF / L2S etc:

```
var slim = from row in db.Customers 
           select new CustomerViewModel {
             Name = row.Name, Id = row.Id };
```

I would expect that to only read 2 columns.

For tools like dapper: since you control the SQL, only specify columns you want - don't use `*`

Comment: I can take this solution, but what If I need to make some changes (which is the case) and save them in the database ?

Comment: @Schneider yep, that sucks; most ORMs are going to want a full object for that. Options: 1: pay the price of that; 2: make sure any "big" columns are lazy-load so you can at least pay a *reduced* price of that; 3: refactor the data into multiple tables, so you can update the "core" cheaply; 4: do the updates via raw SQL

Answer (score -1):

You can create a second project with a code-first DbContext, POCO's and maps that return the subset of columns that you require.

This is a case of cut and paste code but it will get you what you need.

You can just create classes and project the data into them but I'm not sure you can make updates using this method. You can use anonymous types within a single method but you'll need actual classes to pass around between methods.

Another option would be to move to a code first development.

Comment: Actualy the data is a DataContract (WCF) so basically read/write.

Comment: @Schneider do you need the subsets of column data to be writeable?

Comment: Yes, and I want to be able to serialize just some columns so I can control the flow of data that goes over the network.

Comment: @Schneider - the other options won't enable this